# How to Get HTML Element By ID/Class in Erlang?

Tags: html, class, parsing, erlang

I want to replace content within an html element.

In JS it's possible to use `document.getElementById(id)`. And it's not difficult to write the same function for getting elements by Class using `getElementsByTagName()` function.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel. That is why I'm really interested whether there're any libraries which can help to parse (get/set by id/class) HTML in Erlang.

Comment: Which Erlang HTTP library (or Web framework) are you using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are parsing xhtml then you could use [xmerl_xpath](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/xmerl_xpath.html) to select elements. If it is not xhtml, I don't know of any tools which can do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

*Webmachine* is not a real "web framework". It's more like a REST toolkit and it does its job extremely well. Said that, I would strongly discourage you from doing the HTML manipulation directly in the Webmachine resources, mixing Erlang and HTML in a total mess. Instead, separate the controller (the webmachine resource) from the view (the HTML pages), using a templating language - such as [ErlyDTL](http://code.google.com/p/erlydtl/) - and keep doing the HTML manipulation using JS. Use the right tool for the right job.